# c# string format issue for money

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I need to convert a string to a monetary format of {###}.###.###,##

that is

a value of 5461497702600

would become

54.614.977.026,00

The numbers become excessively large.

I am using

```
return string.Format("{0:#" + (val < 1000 ? "" : "\\.") + "##0.00}", val);
```

which returns for the example

54614977.026,00

(only one dot)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Out of curiosity, is `5461497702600m.ToString("C", someculture)` where someculture is a culture that has what you want (de-DE, for example), or rather a custom culture with the currency symbol set to an empty string, not sufficient? I'd never do such things manually if someone else can do it :)

Comment: In reference to many of the answers below don't forget that you can avoid hard-coding your separator characters (e.g. don't assume that the Decimal separator is a period symbol in all cultures). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimalseparator.aspx. The full list: CurrencyDecimalSeparator, NumberDecimalSeparator, CurrencyGroupSeparator, and NumberGroupSeparator.

Comment: +1 @OregonGhost/@rohan cragg. I also appreciate all the answers. Acknowledged that I was reinventing the wheel. As an explanation, the original specification (which the client mistranslated) requested only one . and the one , which is how I arrived at the solution in the question. On site about to go live, of course, we learn the truth :) Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is simpler than you seem to think, just use:

```
   decimal number = 5461497702600M;
   string s = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", number );
```

It is essential to use `decimal` here. The #,##0.00 picture is a very standard way of doing this, the output will use the system default symbols and the fromatter is smart enough to repeat the 3 digit grouping as needed. Use the following overload to specify a Culture, this example with the InvariantCulture will always use a decimal point:

```
 string s = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
      "{0:#,##0.00}", number);
```

Comment: That...is...awesome. Thanks. Out of curiosity, when you say it is essential to use decimal...why? and what will happen if I try it with a double? That's the two types I potentially have, although I think I am using decimal throughout.

Comment: @Kamal, if you use double you will see rounding errors in the last digits (much sooner than with decimal). For money, use decimal. Note the 'M' suffix.

Comment: A small nitpick: This will format the number as `5.461.497.702.600,00` while the question specifies that it should be `54.614.977.026,00`. Just divide the number by 100 before applying the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ToString` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18sthszb.aspx) that takes a [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and an `IFormatProvider`.

Then just use `N2` as your format string and use a `CultureInfo` - for example, `de-DE` - that has `.` as the group separator and `,` as the decimal symbol:

```
return (val / 100).ToString("N2", new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

Beware, if `val` is an integer type rather than a floating-point type then dividing by 100 will lose the two least significant digits. To avoid this you can convert the integer value to a `decimal` when dividing:

```
return (val / 100M).ToString("N2", new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do depends on the current culture/regional settings of your machine. In your case, you are trying to use a COMMA as decimal and a decimal as COMMA, thousand's separator

Comment: Yes, agreed. However we are using a cultural setting that is reqiured for the rest of the system that does not support this country monetary format. So I need to do it programatically.